# How to convert foreach loop to while loop?

Tags: php, html

I am currently using a foreach loop to display the data from my database on my website but have just tried to include pagination which is using a while loop.

```
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
  <div class="post clearfix">
    <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/assets/images/' . $post['image']; ?>" alt="" class="post-image">
    <div class="post-preview">
      <h2><a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></h2>
      <i class="far fa-user"> <?php echo $post['username']; ?></i>
      &nbsp;
      <i class="far fa-calendar"> <?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($post['created_at'])); ?></i>
      <p class="preview-text">
        <?php echo html_entity_decode(substr($post['excerpt'], 0, 150) . '...'); ?>
      </p>
      <a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" class="btn read-more">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

}
?>
```

How do I go about transferring the data here/incorporating them both together into the while loop so that the pagination works smoothly and the data remains displayed as it currently is? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop? What's wrong with `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

To convert foreach to while loop. Simply,
Note: if "$posts" is an object array
try this below

```
<?php 
     $i=0;
     while($i < sizeof($posts)){
     $post=$posts[$i++]; ?>
   
     //use $post object in your code
     //something like $post['image']


<?php }?>
```